# update_option with text area containing html and php

Tags: php, database, wordpress

Here's what I have going on.  I have a single form field textarea on a plugin's settings page.  What I have so far is storing the content in the database correctly.  This content will be HTML/PHP, more specifically it will be the content structure and template tags inside a WordPress loop.

I am using this piece of code to insert the data in the form to the database when the form submits.

```
if (isset($_POST["update_settings"])) {
    $customPostLayout = esc_attr($_POST["post-layout"]);  
    update_option('aw_wp_yca_postcontent', $customPostLayout);      
}
```

Then I am displaying that data with this:

```
echo get_option('aw_wp_yca_postcontent');
```

So lets say I have this in the form:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</div>
```

When I go to the frontend where the posts should display I get this:

```
<div id=\"wrapper\"> <?php the_title(); ?> </div>
```

So instead of rendering inside the loop it is just outputting it as a string.  What am I doing wrong here?  I've tried using `eval()`, which is not my preference, also tried various stuff with `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()`.  Clearly I'm not understanding something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put it in the database, you are storing a text string. So when you pull it from the database, you are getting just that, a text string. If you echo a text string, the only code that will get executed is client code (html, javascript, css, etc.) If you would like to execute php code from a string, then yes, you are going to have to use eval, which is not good practice. However, I don't think storing php in the database is good practice either.

That notwithstanding, the reason your eval failed is because eval() expects a string of valid php code, IE, the stuff in between `<?php` and `?>`. Your code starts with html, so if you want it to eval html properly, then you need to edit it a bit.

```
eval("?> <b>foo</b> <?php ;");
```

For example, this will eval properly:

```
$myEvalString="?> ".get_option('aw_wp_yca_postcontent'). "<?php ;";
eval($myEvalString);
```

Another thing you could do to make php run code from a string is to write it to a file, then include it, like this:

```
file_put_contents("/your/file/path/specialCode.php",get_option('aw_wp_yca_postcontent'));
//your loop code...
include '/your/file/path/specialCode.php';
//..
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I could not get your second option to work, kept getting an that said `file_put_contents(filepath/file) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied`.  Your first option did work; however my form submission is still escaping any quotes that are in the html.  And then writing them out to the page with the backslash before them.  Any ideas on this?

Comment: use stripslashes($yourString) to fix the quotes. The permission issue is happening because you probably don't have root access to your server, this varies depending on your hosting plan. do you have root access to your server in ssh? or are you using cpanel? what hosting plan do you have?

Comment: I do have root access, and set the appropriate files to 777 via ssh.  Still no luck.  This is on an internal virtual LAMP server, and not at an outside shared host.  I will try the striplashes() soon and let you know.  Thanks for the update.

Comment: great! if you are still having permission issues, make sure you have set the proper permission to the destination folder as well, not just the files.